# jQuery UI Tabs - ajax php

Tags: php, jquery, ios, user-interface, tabs

I have some really standard jQuery UI tabs that work fine on my Mac in Safari, Chrome and Firefox however the content doesn't load on the iPad / iPhone and I don't understand why, here's a link:

http://www.hostelcities.com/dev/tabbed_layout/jquery-ui-tabs/ajaxjqueryuitabs.php

The first two tabs, Monday and Tuesday are here:

http://www.hostelcities.com/dev/tabbed_layout/jquery-ui-tabs/monday.php
http://www.hostelcities.com/dev/tabbed_layout/jquery-ui-tabs/tuesday.php

I would appreciate some help - thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Tab content shouldn't include any of the standard html tags such as: html, head and body.

Comment: perhaps you should mark your own answer as accepted, so this question wouldn't be one of the "unanswered" ones.